# How to have a carryon message display the value of the last cell in column D?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim XR As Long
    XR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Carryon= MsgBox("Do totals match?" & XR, vbYesNo, "Continue?")
    If carryon = vbYes then 
    'Rest of code
End sub
```

Comment: `cells(xr,4)` ??

Comment: There has to be a better way of finding out whether two totals match than asking the user.

Comment: @jsheeran - if only it were possible to add numbers in Excel..

Comment: How do you make it where it puts a space after the question mark rather than it combining it together?

Comment: `"Do totals match? "`

Comment: @Djhans26 if you show a bit more of your code and what you are trying to achieve, we can help you make it better. Otherwise, SJR gave you the answer already to your current question.